# Show marker only in area polygon

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw, turf

I got task, to plot polygon on map. After finish draw only marker inside a polygon appear on map. I'm done with leaflet.draw and Draw.Event.Created. What method I can use to check which marker inside area of polygon. A function same like a gif below.

[image: Function same like a gif]

Comment: Depends. Where do the markers come from? GeoJSON? Database backend? Network request to a third-party API?

Comment: @IvanSanchez database backend using API, return lat and long in JSON.

Comment: Can you pass a polygon or a bounding box to that API?

Comment: I have a demo page that does this but it does have the markers on the map, the selected markers turn yellow as a new geojson layer. It may help. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Select/PolySelect.html  The selected points are show with a yellow circle marker and the GeoJSON is sent to the console window.

Comment: I using library Turf.js with function pointsWithinPolygon() to find value marker on map within polygon Area. Everything work fine. @IvanSanchez thanks for reply.

Comment: @BillChappell , Thanks for reply and give example.I have some question in your sample given, how you design your marker with radius?

Comment: The selected set is just a new GeoJSON layer. I just made it larger then the original circleMarker, and  sent it to the back so it didn't cover the marker.